# Search Sentinel-2 images using python api

Tags: python, api, sentinel-2

Based on the documentation [here](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#quickstart), I wrote the following script:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date
api = SentinelAPI('user name', 'password', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
polygon = r"C:\fields\filed1.geojson"
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(polygon))

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20170801','20170830'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,30))

products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)
```

I got the expected result. I'm trying to do the same thing but the search needs to be based upon x,y coordinates.

I read [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/FullTextSearch?redirectedfrom=SciHubUserGuide.3FullTextSearch) that I just need to provide the x,y coordinate (as a tuple) to the footprint so I tried:

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI('user name', 'password', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
footprint = (41.9000, 12.5000)

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20170801','20170830'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,30))

products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)
```

and I get an error:

```
SentinelAPIError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-98f8dc400863> in <module>()
      8                      date = ('20170801','20170830'),
      9                      platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
---> 10                      cloudcoverpercentage = (0,30))
     11 
     12 products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)

C:\Users\Ran\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.pyc in query(self, area, date, raw, area_relation, order_by, limit, offset, **keywords)
    132                           order_by, limit, offset, query)
    133         formatted_order_by = _format_order_by(order_by)
--> 134         response, count = self._load_query(query, formatted_order_by, limit, offset)
    135         self.logger.info("Found %s products", count)
    136         return _parse_opensearch_response(response)

C:\Users\Ran\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.pyc in _load_query(self, query, order_by, limit, offset)
    240 
    241     def _load_query(self, query, order_by=None, limit=None, offset=0):
--> 242         products, count = self._load_subquery(query, order_by, limit, offset)
    243 
    244         # repeat query until all results have been loaded

C:\Users\Ran\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.pyc in _load_subquery(self, query, order_by, limit, offset)
    282                 # returned as the total results value when the query string was incorrect.
    283                 raise SentinelAPIError(
--> 284                     'Invalid query string. Check the parameters and format.', response)
    285             total_results = int(json_feed['opensearch:totalResults'])
    286         except (ValueError, KeyError):

SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 200 OK: Invalid query string. Check the parameters and format
```

How can I perform that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation and downloaded everything from command line using sentinelsat on Windows 64. My steps are:

1. Extract bounding box of your polygon as GeoJSON (in QGIS-->convert from shapefile to GeoJSON). You need 4 points that make up your polygon, even if it has another shape.
2. Open anaconda prompt (python version>=3)
3. `pip install sentinelsat`
4. cd \your_folder where you want to download
5. `sentinelsat -u your username -p your password -g \path\to\polygon.geojson -s start_of_interval -e end_of_interval --sentinel 2 --cloud 40 -d`

This last expression downloads all Sentinel 2 images with a max of 40% cloud coverage.

Comment: What do I do if my polygon contains more (or less) than 4 points? can I choose between sentinel-2 products (i.e., TOA or surface reflectance)?

Comment: Use the bounding box in QGis, which extracts a polygon made of 4 corners that enclose your entire polygon.

Answer (score 0):

`sentinelsat` accepts any WKT geometry as area parameter. If you want to query images that intersect with a point you would do:

```
aoi = 'POINT (41.9 12.5)'
products = api.query(aoi,
                     date = ('20170801','20170830'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,30))
```

See also the documentation of the Python API: https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPI.query